# Which are the most common Latin words/phrases used in spoken English?

Tags: phrases, american-english, british-english, latin, speech

Please, specify American/British Engilsh!
I think these below are very common but I have no idea if they are commonly used in spoken English.

ad hoc
per se
a priori
de facto
ergo
et cetera
vice versa

Edit: Which are the Latin words/phrases understood and used by everyone?

Comment: Wonder which (how many) English words/ phrases are **not** (from) Latin.

Comment: Isn't this readily available information from COCA etc?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Spoken!

Comment: Oh, no, Edwin Ashforth has a good point.  COCA does have transcriptions of 95 million words of (unscripted) spoken English.  (I'm not certain how representative they are of spoken English in general.)

Comment: @Kris: About 2/3: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Origins_of_English_PieChart.svg

Comment: @Kris: Of course, there's a lot of indirect Latin influence through some of the other languages as well.

Comment: I put up a [list of Latin phrases](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Latinphrases.pdf) for the students in my freshman etymology class to look up. It's not definitive, but it's long.

Answer (score 2):

I searched the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/), limiting results to the spoken sub-corpus, which contains 95 million words of unscripted spoken English.  I included whatever alternative spellings or misspellings I could think of; since my goal here was to find words as they were spoken, spelling was irrelevant.

Here's the raw data:

```
  et cetera         1529
  (etcetera)        208
  (etc)             813
  ad hoc            94
  a priori          3
  de facto          221
  (de facto)        3
  ergo              19
  vice versa        253
  (vise versa)      1
  per se            459
  (per say)         6
```

Combining the above and sorting in descending order, I get these results:

```
  et cetera         2550    (most common)
  per se            465
  vice versa        254
  de facto          224
  ad hoc            94
  ergo              19
  a priori          3       (least common)
```

These results may not reflect spoken American English in general.  They don't represent British English, which may or may not be different.

These results correspond roughly with my intuition as a native speaker of American English, for what it's worth.  All of these lexical items are used in spoken English, but not all are used with equal frequency.

Answer (score 1):

ad hoc -- common among academic writers, widely known among educated people, but not common in casual speech

per se -- reasonably common among everyone educated, but not that common in casual speech.

a priori -- only in legal and academic writing.

de facto -- common among educated people, widely used in newspapers and journals, but not that common in speech.

ergo -- pretentious, not used, but widely understood. often used to make fun of people who are acting too sophisticated.

et cetera -- understood and used by everyone in all registers of language. sometimes colloquially pronounced "egg cetera" especially among less educated people.

vice versa -- understood and used by everyone. first syllable is pronounced to rhyme with "nice" as though it were a native English word. Sometimes colloquially prnounced "vice-a versa."